# Отделение реализации объектов, параметризированных enum

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Привет.

Имеется ряд объектов с разной реализацией, но единым интерфейсом:

```
public interface IComponent<Tin, Tout>
    where Tin : struct
    where Tout : struct
{ 
    IParameters<Tin, Tout> ComponentParameters { get; }
    ...
}
```

Tin, Tout - enum'ы, отдельные для каждого типа объектов. В них содержится перечень параметров, необходимых для организации словарей:

```
public interface IParameters<Tin, Tout>
    where Tin : struct
    where Tout : struct
{
    Dictionary<Tin, string> InputStruct { get; }
    Dictionary<Tout, string> OutputStruct { get; }
}
```

Объекты те являются составными элементами составного объекта. На данный момент это реализовано частично как набором полей и свойств:

```
private List<Component1> _cmp1; // Component1 : IParameters<Tin1, Tout1>
private List<Component2> _cmp2; // Component2 : IParameters<Tin2, Tout2>
...
public List<Component1> Comp1 { get { return _cmp1; } set { _cmp1 = value; } }
public List<Component2> Comp2 { get { return _cmp2; } set { _cmp2 = value; } }
...
```

, так и набором полей и методов доступа к ним:

```
private List<Component3> _cmp3;
private List<Component4> _cmp4;
...
public List<T> GetComponent34<T>() { ... }
public int SetComponent34<T>(List<T> value) { ... }
```

Каждый тип объектов базируется в отдельной сборке.
Хочется отделить реализацию составного объекта от особенностей составляющих, не позволяющих запихнуть их все, например, в один список. Главными из них естественно являются enum'ы. Однако, как это сделать, мне в голову что-то не приходит.

P.S. Ещё вполне возможно, что перечни параметров будут загружаться не из енумов, а из внешнего источника, но пока хотелось бы решить вопрос именно с енумами.

Comment: А можете попробовать еще раз объяснить проблему другим способом? Что в каких сборках базируется и что от чего надо отделать. Я вот прочитал три раза и так и не понял...

Comment: @andreycha , допустим, есть сборки:
Component1.dll
Component2.dll
...

В каждой из сборок определён соответствующий _ComponentX_, реализующий интерфейс _IComponent<Tin, Tout>_.
Для каждого _ComponentX_ существуют свои собственные enum'ы _EnumInX_ и _EnumOutX_, которые подставляются в параметры интерфейса. Соответственно, если пытаться запихнуть _Component1_, _Component2_ и т.д. в один List, отличающиеся _EnumIn(Out)1_, _EnumIn(Out)2_ и т.д. не позволят это сделать.

Comment: @andrey , неужели таки нет употребимых способов привести эти енумы к одному интерфейсу?

Comment: А какой тип списка вы используете? `List<IComponent<???, ???>>` -- что вы хотите указать в качестве типов-параметров?

Comment: @andrey , выше по теме. Dictionary. А типы - enum.

Comment: Почему `Dictionary`? Вы же сами писал *"если пытаться запихнуть `Component1`, `Component2` и т.д. в один `List`"*. Добавьте в вопрос код, в котором вы пытаетесь засунуть их в один лист

Comment: @andrey , в вопросе код есть. Внимательней.
_public interface IParameters<Tin, Tout>_ <= словари там

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем, ушёл от проблемы, изменив тип ключей в словарях на строковый.